# Picker item source binding from view model

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind the values for a picker from  a model in view model, there I am getting path of the model instead of the values.

```
<Picker x:Name="LocationPicker"
    Title="Location" HeightRequest="40"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Location}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MaintainRoomTypes}"/>
```

Here is my view model code:

```
if (jobDetailsForFitter != null)
{
    WindowDetails = new WindowDetailsModel
    {
        Windows = jobDetailsForFitter.Windows,
        Locations = jobDetailsForFitter.Locations,
        RoomTypes = jobDetailsForFitter.RoomTypes,
        AddFiles = jobDetailsForFitter.AddFiles
    };

    Locations = jobDetailsForFitter.Locations;

    MaintainRoomTypes = jobDetailsForFitter.RoomTypes;

    await FitterService.Instance.LoadJobDetailsToLocalStore(jobDetailsForFitter, SelectedJob?.Id ?? 0);
}
```

how to bind itemsource to get list.

```
public List<Room> Locations { get; set; }
public List<RoomTypeModel> RoomTypes { get; set; }
```

Comment: ItemSourcers is binded to MaintainRoomTypes  not Locations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define `ItemDisplayBinding` property to `Picker`.

For eg:

```
public class Room
{
public string RoomNumber { private set; get; }
public string RoomName { private set; get; }
}
```

And you want to display **RoomName** in **Picker**

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Room}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding RoomName}"/>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for help @This is the one iam looking for.But here i am not getting selected item from picker,is there any way to get selected item from the picker to view model?

Comment: <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Room}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding RoomName}" SelectedItem="{Binding RoomSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />

and define RoomSelected in ViewModel like this 

public Room RoomSelected 
        {
            get { return _RoomSelected ; }
            set
            {
                _RoomSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: Thanks again@Sandesh Acharya.